# Finding constants from normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

The question is the following: Let $X\sim N(10,4)$. Find $a$ and $b$ such that $a+bX\sim N(0,1)$.

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: $4$ stands for $σ$ or for $σ^2$?

Comment: Hallo slaiman, are you there? Can you answer my question so that I can answer yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may recall that 
$$
X \sim N(m,\sigma) 
$$ is equivalent to
$$
Z=\frac{X -m}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1) 
$$ giving here

> $$
> b=\frac12,\quad a=-5.
> $$

Comment: @Oliver Oloa thank u as well for your answer! It really helped.

Comment: There is also a second solution, with the reverse signs.

Comment: You should make an edit. Jimmy R has already posted the right comment.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $σ^2_X=4$ \begin{align}\Bbb E[a+bX]&=a+b\Bbb E[X]=a+10b\\[0.2cm]{\rm Var}(a+bX)&=0+b^2{\rm Var}(X)=4b^2\end{align} So solve the system \begin{cases}a+10b&=0\\4b^2&=1\end{cases} which has two different solutions.

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Comment: @JimmyR thanks for your answer !